# Merged git branches with differences in source code?

Tags: git, version-control

I have two branches: origin/master and origin/dev.

This is how my process is supposed to work:

> Each time I create a new feature, I branch off of origin/master. When testing, I merge the feature branch into origin/dev.
>
> If the test is successful, I merge the feature into origin/master. Then I reset origin/dev using:
>
> git checkout origin/dev
>      git reset --hard origin/master
>      git push -F origin/dev
>
> If the test is unsuccessful, I simply reset origin/dev and debug on the feature branch.

Something got screwed up recently, and now when running my program, I see different behavior between origin/master and origin/dev.

Both branches are currently pointing to the same commit. Is it possible for two synced branches to contain differences in their source code without git diff being able to pick it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's impossible.

- If you sync with two branches, that means the two branches are point to the same commit and the two branches contain same code.
- If you need the two branches contain different source code, you shouldn’t sync with them.

So if the `origin/master` and `origin/dev` have different source code, you should change the way to reset `origin/dev` branch as below:

```
git checkout origin/dev
git reset --hard HEAD~
# If you were not puch the changes after merging feature branch into origin/dev, it’s not necessary to force push
```

Since `origin/master` and `origin/dev` are contain the same code now, you can reset or checkout the right files to each branch separately.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. It turned out to be a problem with my deployment scripts.